# I want to align my text in vim editor with respect to a common character

Tags: vim

suppose I have to align this text so that the last digit in every line comes in a single column

```
begin: Tx_Arbiter_Reg4 
type: CONFIG
width: 32
field: RESERVED                                        31:22 {Reserved}
field: cfg_txarb_max_credits_xgnet                      21:0  {Maximum value credits that XGEthernet can accumulate. Credits will saturate at this level. As a general rule, this value should be programmed to 2* cfg_txarb_initial_credits_xgenet}
default: 32'h0020_0000
end

begin: Tx_Arbiter_Reg5 
type: CONFIG
width: 32
field: RESERVED                                        31:16 {Reserved}
field: cfg_txarb_rdma_pause_priority                    15:8 {Pause priority for RDMA traffic}
field: cfg_txarb_xgenet_pause_priority                7:0 {Pause priority for Xgenet traffic}
default: 32'h0000_8001
end

begin: Tx_Arbiter_Reg6 
type: CONFIG
width: 32
field: RESERVED                                        31:2 {Reserved}
field: cfg_rdma_pause_wq_en                              1 {Not supported}
field: cfg_xgenet_pause_wq_en                            0 {1=XGEthernet Work queues corresponding the Rx PPP packet are paused. 0=XGEthernet datapath (all priorities) are paused.}
default: 32'h0000_0001
end
```

Comment: Please add the desired outcome to your question.

Answer (score 2):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)

All come with extensive documentation, so you hopefully should be able to figure out how to align according to your requirements!